# What is 'sys.is_finalizing' and when it's useful?

Tags: python, python-3.x, sys

The `sys` module have a function called `is_finalizing`. Running `help(sys.is_finalizing)` will result in

```
>>> help(sys.is_finalizing)
Help on built-in function is_finalizing in module sys:

is_finalizing()
    Return True if Python is exiting.
```

What is mean by *Python is exiting*? The [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.is_finalizing) says this,

> `sys.is_finalizing()`
> Return `True` if the Python interpreter is shutting
> down, `False` otherwise

I am quite not understand what *Python interpreter is shutting down* means. Does it mean during the `exit` function call, If yes what's the point of `sys.is_finalizing()` as it always return `False`?. I am trying to understand in which scenario `sys.is_finalizing` return `True` and in which situation this API is useful?

Comment: Think about `finally:` blocks and such, or `__del__` finalizers being invoked. It's not guaranteed whether they'll finish during shutdown. Sometimes it's valuable to just give up and not _try_ to perform an operation if doing so will put your application in a state where it's likely to encounter more failures in the near future.

Comment: ...anyhow -- it's a for-advanced-users thing. If you don't know why it might be necessary, you don't need it; the people who need it _know_ they need it, because they've run into bugs caused by Python's mid-shutdown behavior. If you're not trying to do anything fancy enough to trigger those bugs, it's not a thing you need to think about.

Comment: ...to get a rough sense, though, you might start by reading the warnings in https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__del__. If you want to write a finalizer that runs in normal cases, but _doesn't_ attempt to run when you're in the process of shutdown and may not be able to refer to external modules or other things that are in the process of being evicted from memory... well, that's an example of a use case.

Comment: (To be clear, I strongly dislike "what's facility X good for?" questions, because they tend to ask for definitive answers to open-ended questions, and thus are by nature too broad to be on-topic)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not something most users would ever need, but `is_finalizing()` will be `True` while the interpreter is shutting down, when it's destroying objects, releasing memory, etc. Knowing that the interpreter is shutting down when an object's `__del__()` method is called might let the object decide to take certain actions, or not.

As a quick display in an interactive session:

```
>>> import sys
>>> class X:
...     def __del__(self):
...         print(f"__del__: is_finalizing = {sys.is_finalizing()}")
...
>>> x = X()
>>> del x
__del__: is_finalizing = False
>>>
>>> x = X()
>>> sys.is_finalizing()
False
>>> exit()
__del__: is_finalizing = True
```

Note that, per the [Python Data Model](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__del__), there's no guarantee `__del__()` will be called:

> It is not guaranteed that `__del__()` methods are called for objects that still exist when the interpreter exits.

(For completeness, note that the example happens to show the object getting deleted immediately as a result of the name being removed with  `del x`, but that behavior is not guaranteed either.)